# When including Bearer in request I get CORS error, IdentityServer4, Api, angular

Tags: asp.net-web-api, typescript, asp.net-core-1.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am having trouble to getting data after I have logged in.

I am using IdentityServer4 with a WebApi. Everything is working as long as I dont send any authorization berarer. I am using the authorizationinterceptor from Damien Bod.

When I am sending the bearer I get this back:

> GET https://localhost:44373/api/pages/10  10:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot
>   load https://localhost:44373/api/pages/10. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

This works as long as I don't add the Authorization header to the http request.

I am using the IdentityServer sample found here:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/dev/MVC%20and%20API/src

And both the security service and authorization interceptor found here:
https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5IdentityServerAngularImplicitFlow

So the problem is after I have logged in and trying to retrieve data from API, I get the above error.

API - Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        if (env.IsEnvironment("Development"))
        {
            // This will push telemetry data through Application Insights pipeline faster, allowing you to view results immediately.
            builder.AddApplicationInsightsSettings(developerMode: true);
        }

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();

        //services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
        //                                                            .AllowAnyMethod()
        //                                                             .AllowAnyHeader()));

        //var policy = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsPolicy();

        //policy.Headers.Add("*");
        //policy.Methods.Add("*");
        //policy.Origins.Add("*");
        //policy.SupportsCredentials = true;

        //services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("AllowAll", policy));

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<AsklepiosContext>(options =>               
                options.UseSqlServer(@"Server = .\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection = true; Database = AsklepiosTrunk; MultipleActiveResultSets = true;"));

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        var guestPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .RequireClaim("scope", "api1")
            .Build();

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(guestPolicy));
        });

        //DI
        // some services here .. 


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        //app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        //JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //var jwtBearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions()
        //{
        //    Authority = "https://localhost:44301",
        //    Audience = "https://localhost:44301/resources",
        //    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,

        //    // required if you want to return a 403 and not a 401 for forbidden responses
        //    AutomaticChallenge = true
        //};

        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerOptions);

        //JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        //var jwtBearerOptions = new JwtBearerOptions()
        //{
        //    Authority = "https://localhost:44302",
        //    Audience = "https://localhost:44302/resources",
        //    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,

        //    // required if you want to return a 403 and not a 401 for forbidden responses
        //    AutomaticChallenge = true,
        //};

        //app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerOptions);

        //JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseCors(policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins(
                "http://localhost:3000");

            policy.AllowAnyHeader();
            policy.AllowAnyMethod();
        });


        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "https://localhost:44301",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ScopeName = "api1",
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        });

        //app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        //{
        //    Authority = "https://localhost:44301",
        //    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

        //    ScopeName = "dataEventRecords",
        //    AutomaticAuthenticate = true
        //});

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

AuthorizationInterceptor.ts

```
import { urls } from "../constants";

class AuthorizationInterceptor {
private static _instance: AuthorizationInterceptor;
private baseUrl: string;

public static Factory($q: angular.IQService, localStorageService, $window) {
    AuthorizationInterceptor._instance = new AuthorizationInterceptor($q, localStorageService, $window);
    return AuthorizationInterceptor._instance;
}

constructor(private $q: angular.IQService, private localStorageService, private $window) {
    console.log("AuthorizationInterceptor created");
}

public request(requestSuccess) {
    const self = AuthorizationInterceptor._instance;
    requestSuccess.headers = requestSuccess.headers || {};

        if (self.localStorageService.get("authorizationData") !== null &&
            self.localStorageService.get("authorizationData") !== "") {
            // when it adds this header i get CORS Error
            requestSuccess.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + self.localStorageService.get("authorizationData");
        }

        return requestSuccess || self.$q.when(requestSuccess);
}


public responseError(responseFailure) {
    const self = AuthorizationInterceptor._instance;
    console.log("console.log(responseFailure);");
    console.log(responseFailure);

    if (responseFailure.status === 403) {
        alert("forbidden");
        self.$window.location = "https://localhost:44389/forbidden";
        self.$window.href = "forbidden";

    } else if (responseFailure.status === 401) {

        alert("unauthorized");
        self.localStorageService.set("authorizationData", "");
    }

    return self.$q.reject(responseFailure);
}
}

export default AuthorizationInterceptor;
```

SecurityService.ts

```
import DataService from "./dataservice";
import { urls } from "../constants";

class SecurityService {
private baseUrl: string;
private isAuthorized: boolean = false;
private hasAdminRole: boolean = false;

constructor(private $http, private $log, private $q, private $rootScope, private $window, private $state,
    private localStorageService, private $stateParams) {
    this.baseUrl = `${urls.baseApiUrl}`;
    console.log("return url: " + this.$stateParams.returnurl);
    $log.info("SecurityService called");

    // what to put this ?
    this.$rootScope.IsAuthorized = false;
    this.$rootScope.HasAdminRole = false;
}

public resetAuthorizationData() {
    this.localStorageService.set("authorizationData", "");
    this.localStorageService.set("authorizationDataIdToken", "");
    this.$rootScope.IsAuthorized = false;
    this.$rootScope.HasAdminRole = false;
}

public setAuthorizationData(token, id_token) {
    if (this.localStorageService.get("authorizationData") !== "") {
        this.localStorageService.set("authorizationData", "");
    }

    this.localStorageService.set("authorizationData", token);
    this.localStorageService.set("authorizationDataIdToken", id_token);
    this.$rootScope.IsAuthorized = true;

    let data: any = this.getDataFromToken(token);
    if (data.role !== undefined) {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.role.length; i++) {
            if (data.role[i] === "dataEventRecords.admin") {
                this.$rootScope.HasAdminRole = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

 public authorize() {
    console.log("AuthorizedController time to log on");

    // GET /authorize?
    // response_type=code%20id_token
    // &client_id=s6BhdRkqt3
    // &redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb
    // &scope=openid%20profile%data
    // &nonce=n-0S6_WzA2Mj
    // &state=af0ifjsldkj HTTP/1.1

    const authorizationUrl = "https://localhost:44302/connect/authorize";
    const client_id = "angularclient";
    const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/authorized";
    const response_type = "id_token token";
    const scope = "openid profile api1";
    const nonce = "N" + Math.random() + "" + Date.now();
    const state = Date.now() + "" + Math.random();

    this.localStorageService.set("authNonce", nonce);
    this.localStorageService.set("authStateControl", state);
    console.log("AuthorizedController created. adding myautostate: " + this.localStorageService.get("authStateControl"));

    const url =
        authorizationUrl + "?" +
        "response_type=" + encodeURI(response_type) + "&" +
        "client_id=" + encodeURI(client_id) + "&" +
        "redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(redirect_uri) + "&" +
        "scope=" + encodeURI(scope) + "&" +
        "nonce=" + encodeURI(nonce) + "&" +
        "state=" + encodeURI(state);

    this.$window.location = url;
}

public doAuthorization() {
    this.resetAuthorizationData();
    if (this.$window.location.hash) {
        this.authorizeCallback();
    } else {
        this.authorize();
    }
}

public logoff() {
    // var id_token = localStorageService.get("authorizationDataIdToken");
    // var authorizationUrl = 'https://localhost:44330/connect/endsession';
    // var id_token_hint = id_token;
    // var post_logout_redirect_uri = 'https://localhost:44347/unauthorized.html';
    // var state = Date.now() + "" + Math.random();

    // var url =
    //    authorizationUrl + "?" +
    //    "id_token_hint=" + id_token_hint + "&" +
    //    "post_logout_redirect_uri=" + encodeURI(post_logout_redirect_uri) + "&" +
    //    "state=" + encodeURI(state);

    // ResetAuthorizationData();
    // $window.location = url;

    // 19.02.2106: temp until connect/endsession is implemented in IdentityServer4 NOT A PROPER SOLUTION!
    this.resetAuthorizationData();
    this.$window.location = "https://localhost:44389/unauthorized.html";
}

private urlBase64Decode(str) {
    let output = str.replace("-", "+").replace("_", "/");
        switch (output.length % 4) {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 2:
                output += "==";
                break;
            case 3:
                output += "=";
                break;
            default:
                throw "Illegal base64url string!";
        }
        return window.atob(output);
}

private getDataFromToken(token) {
    let data = {};
    if (typeof token !== "undefined") {
        let encoded = token.split(".")[1];
        data = JSON.parse(this.urlBase64Decode(encoded));
    }
    return data;
}

private authorizeCallback() {
    console.log("AuthorizedController created, has hash");
    let hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    let result: any = hash.split("&").reduce(function (result2, item) {
        let parts = item.split("=");
        result2[parts[0]] = parts[1];
        return result2;
    }, {});

    let token = "";
    let id_token = "";
    let authResponseIsValid = false;
    if (!result.error) {

        if (result.state !== this.localStorageService.get("authStateControl")) {
            console.log("AuthorizedCallback incorrect state");
        } else {

            token = result.access_token;
            id_token = result.id_token;

            let dataIdToken: any = this.getDataFromToken(id_token);
            console.log(dataIdToken);

            // validate nonce
            if (dataIdToken.nonce !== this.localStorageService.get("authNonce")) {
                console.log("AuthorizedCallback incorrect nonce");
            } else {
                this.localStorageService.set("authNonce", "");
                this.localStorageService.set("authStateControl", "");

                authResponseIsValid = true;
                console.log("AuthorizedCallback state and nonce validated, returning access token");
            }
        }
    }

    if (authResponseIsValid) {
        this.setAuthorizationData(token, id_token);
        console.log(this.localStorageService.get("authorizationData"));

        this.$state.go("overviewindex");
    } else {
        this.resetAuthorizationData();
        this.$state.go("unauthorized");
    }
}
}

SecurityService.$inject = ["$http", "$log", "$q", "$rootScope", "$window",      "$state", "localStorageService", "$stateParams"];
export default SecurityService;
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be CORS issue. Enable CORS in your service and you will be good to go. When you add authorization header, this made the request *not simple* in MDN terms. And this might have triggered pre flight OPTIONS request. You can read more about CORS here - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

**UPDATE**  - you have code for enabling CORS in your code, you have commented it out. Instead on giving full permission (*), give specific for your domain

Comment: i tried this instead  
var policy = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsPolicy();

            policy.Headers.Add("*");
            policy.Methods.Add("*");
            policy.Origins.Add("*");
            policy.SupportsCredentials = true;

            services.AddCors(x => x.AddPolicy("AllowAll", policy));
But i get same error

Comment: But when I remove the authorizationData cookie it works. But still need that token

Comment: CORS is working when I am not sending authorization bearer.

Comment: Try policy.Headers.Add("*")

Comment: Or  for testing, try these lines alone  - var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(corsAttr);

Comment: @n3tx - any luck?

Comment: Nope, didn't work with policy.Headers.Add("*") and the EnableCorsAttribute is not available in aspnetcore 1.0 I don't have any HttpConfiguration in the startup.cs file

Comment: You don't have a CORS policy named "AllowAll" defined, but you have asked to use it. You have that policy commented out.

Comment: I have tried different aproaches and none of them work. I dont know what to do more.

Comment: How come the CORS is working without that Authorization attribute ?

Comment: Just for testing, try enabling cors explicitly for that controller and give full permission...

Comment: Because you have set custom header..in cors you can specify the allowed headers and the header you are setting is not in that list. Make sure the allowed verbsinclude OPTIONS verb as well

Comment: I tried this [EnableCors("AllowAll")] on top of the action method in the controller. Didn't work either. I have tried adding cors inside both Configure and ConfigureServices methods. Does not work either. I dont know what to try next ? Everything is working when not included that authorization header. That's weird.

Comment: Do you think it can be something in the authorizationinterceptor that is not working as it should ?

Comment: Your interceptor is fine and it adds Authorization header to the request. But this header causes a pre-flight OPTIONS request if the request is cross domain. Could you please confirm whether you are getting error in this OPTIONS request?

Comment: Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:204 No Content - and the GET Method: Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error - THis is after I have logged in

Comment: That means OPTIONS pre flight request went through fine. Could you get the request headers of the GET request?

Comment: Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiI....

Comment: I tried it with Postman, and I get same error there when adding the authorization header.

Comment: Remove authorization header and try with some other dummy header, let's see if it's specific to auth header or with all custom headers

Comment: It works with a dummy header.. I tried to add a equal sign before the Bearer and now it works. But when I try to get data from an [Authorize] method I get 401. So maybe the "=" sign does'nt do anything ?

Comment: Nah .. I tried with whatever sign in front of Bearer and I get the data from API but i dont think it sends the Bearer.. So I don't think it works. That's why I still get 401

Comment: When I added the equal sign to the "= Bearer" I get the data from the API (only anonymous). So the = adds nothing. Without the = i get cors error.

Comment: So in what scenario are you getting 401?

Comment: When I add the equal sign like "= Bearer" in the interceptor. But I dont think it sends the Authorization then

Comment: I mean config.headers['Authorization'] =  'Basic your_token_here' . Just a try.

Comment: I changed the Bearer to Basic in the interceptor. And I dont get any cors error, and a 401 when trying to access an authorize method. So it seems that Bearer is the problem

Comment: Interesting...btw what kind of token is that, Bearer or basic or jwt token? And could you please add an update to your question with the code changes you did to reach till here. It would be readable if you could remove the comments..

Comment: Good question.. How can I see that ? I am getting the token from the IdentityServer (IdentityServer4).

Comment: The API got this app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(jwtBearerOptions); So I guess it's a JWT token ?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need custom imp an ICorsPolicyService interface and DI it.

```
public class SwaggerCorsPolicyService : DefaultCorsPolicyService, ICorsPolicyService
{
    private readonly IClientService _clientService;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public SwaggerCorsPolicyService(ILoggerFactory logger, IClientService clientService) : base(logger.CreateLogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>())
    {
        this._clientService = clientService;
        this._logger = logger.CreateLogger<SwaggerCorsPolicyService>();
    }

    async Task<bool> ICorsPolicyService.IsOriginAllowedAsync(string origin)
    {
        if (AllowAll)
        {
            _logger.LogDebug("AllowAll true, so origin: {0} is allowed", origin);
            return true;
        }

        AllowedOrigins = await _clientService.**Get All Client Uris**;
        if (AllowedOrigins != null)
        {
            if (AllowedOrigins.Contains(origin, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("AllowedOrigins configured and origin {0} is allowed", origin);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("AllowedOrigins configured and origin {0} is not allowed", origin);
            }
        }
        _logger.LogDebug("Exiting; origin {0} is not allowed", origin);
        return false;
    }
```

### }

in ConfigureServices

```
var icps = services.Where(p => p.ServiceType == typeof(ICorsPolicyService)).FirstOrDefault();
if (icps != null) services.Remove(icps);
services.AddTransient<ICorsPolicyService, SwaggerCorsPolicyService>();
```

Comment: In which project? IdentityServer ot the Api ?

Comment: I tried with both * and http://localhost:3000 .. like "AllowedOrigins = new List<string> {"http://localhost:3000"};

Comment: @n3tx in IdentityServer project, is still not running?

Comment: I get this error now:  Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44361/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Answer (score 0):

I've also run into this same issue and after some troubles I figured out that the error had nothing to do with CORS.

You should check the logs of your API. In my case the error was that the bearer token had expired or some other authentication mechanism had crashed, but the browser detected it as CORS problem due to the lack of the proper header.

Fortunatelly, IDSRV4 has a good logging system so you should check the API output logs.